# Establecer patrón de regex que permita la extracción y reubicación de info bajo ciertas condiciones, evitando casos de greedy-matchings innecesarias

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, regex, str-replace

Aquí mi programa (incompleto) hecho en python; en el que tengo algunos problemas con el reemplazo de la información identificada usando la función `re.sub()`

```py
import re

input_text = "8 dias despues del 2022-12-22 o 10 dias antes de este"  #example 1
input_text = "8 dias despues del dia 2022-12-22 o 10 dias despues de ese dia en donde paso"  #example 2
input_text = "8 dias antes o 9 dias antes del 2022-12-22"  #example 3
input_text = "2 dias despues o 1 dia antes del 2022-12-22, dia en donde ocurrio"  #example 4
input_text = "a tan solo 2 dias despues de 2022-12-22 o a caso eran 6 dias despues, mmm no recuerdo bien"  #example 5
input_text = "a tan solo 2 dias despues de 2022-12-22 o a caso eran 6 dias despues de 2022-12-18, mmm no recuerdo bien"  #example 6


some_text = r"(?:(?!\.\s*?\n)[^;])*"

date_format = r"\d*-\d{2}-\d{2}"
date_capture_pattern = r"([12]\d{3}-[01]\d-[0-3]\d)(\D*?)"

previous_days = r"(\d+)\s*(?:dias|dia)\s*(?:antes|previo|antes|atrás|atras)\s*"
after_days = r"(\d+)\s*(?:dias|dia)\s*(?:después|despues|luego)\s*"

n_patterns = [
previous_days + r"(?:del|de\s*el|de|al|a)\s*" + some_text + date_capture_pattern + some_text + r"\s*(?:,\s*o|o)\s*" + previous_days,
after_days + r"(?:del|de\s*el|de|al|a)\s*" + some_text + date_capture_pattern + some_text + r"\s*(?:,\s*o|o)\s*" + previous_days,
previous_days + r"(?:del|de\s*el|de|al|a)\s*" + some_text + date_capture_pattern + some_text + r"\s*(?:,\s*o|o)\s*" + after_days,
after_days + r"(?:del|de\s*el|de|al|a)\s*" + some_text + date_capture_pattern + some_text + r"\s*(?:,\s*o|o)\s*" + after_days]

#Itero la lista de patrones de búsqueda para que el programa intente con uno por uno
for n_pattern in n_patterns:
    #Este es mi intento de realizar el reemplazo, aunque tiene problemas con modificadores non-greedy
    input_text = re.sub(n_pattern,  , input_text, re.IGNORECASE)


print(repr(input_text))  # --> output
```

En caso de alguna de estas condiciones de búsqueda, haga los reemplazos y elimine estas frases en el medio `(?:de\s*ese\s*día|de\s*este\s*día|de\s*ese\s*dia|de\s*este\s*dia|de\s*este)`

Además, estoy teniendo problemas para colocar el argumento necesario para que se realice este reemplazo en esta línea de código `input_text = re.sub(n_pattern,  , input_text, re.IGNORECASE)`

Tampoco he establecido un número máximo de sustituciones, ya que dentro de una misma cadena puede haber más de un caso consecutivo en el que se deba realizar el mismo proceso, aunque creo que esto no será un problema para el `re.sub()`  función porque sé que por defecto ya tiende a buscar y modificar tantos casos de coincidencias como encuentra

El **output** que necesitaría obtener en cada uno de los ejemplos seria el siguiente:

```
"8 dias despues del 2022-12-22 o 10 dias antes del 2022-12-22"   #for example 1
"8 dias despues del dia 2022-12-22 o 10 dias despues del 2022-12-22 en donde paso"   #for example 2
"8 dias antes del 2022-12-22 o 9 dias antes del 2022-12-22"   #for example 3
"2 dias despues del 2022-12-22 o 1 dia antes del 2022-12-22, dia en donde ocurrio"   #for example 4
"a tan solo 2 dias despues de 2022-12-22 o a caso eran 6 dias despues del 2022-12-22, mmm no recuerdo bien"   #for example 5
"a tan solo 2 dias despues de 2022-12-22 o a caso eran 6 dias despues de 2022-12-18, mmm no recuerdo bien"   #for example 6, no recibe modificaciones
```

Comment: No creo que las expresiones regulares sean el camino. Tal vez la solución puede ser un parser que reconozca fechas y expresiones con ellas.

Comment: ¿No sería más fácil normalizar las expresiones en lugar de tratar de "adaptarlas"? O sea, reducir todos a "n días antes/después del aaaa-mm-dd"

Comment: he intentado ya de varias formas pero ya las he normalizado por eso todas estan en este orden `2022-12-22` , el problema es que en este proceso de normalización debo extraer los valores anteriores y concatenarlos de un modo que quede como las a salidas. Mmm quizás una combinación de concatenación y el `re.sub()` sirva, almenos eso estoy intentando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución sin usar expresiones regulares. Es una primera aproximación, sin manejo de errores ni excepciones, a fin de destacar la esencia del método.

La solución es construir una función que avance por una subexpresión ("fue 8 días después del 2022-01-01") e identifique: el número de días, la fecha y la relación antes/después)

```
lista_dias = ["día", "días", "dia", "dias"]

def analizar(subfrase):
    #   Recibe una expresión como "a 8 días antes del 2022-02-21"
    #   y extrae los dias, la relación y la fecha.

    #   Eliminamos los signos ortográficos que molestan
    fecha = subfrase.replace(",", "").replace(".", "").replace(";", "")

    #   Usar un iterador, lo que nos permite avanzar por la lista de
    #   palabras en distintas partes del código.

    iterador = iter(fecha.split())

    #   Las variables que queremos detectar y retornar
    dias = None             # El número de días.
    antesdespues = None     # La relación antes/después
    fecha = None            # La fecha a la que hace referencia.

    #   Buscar el primer valor entero para comenzar el análisis.
    while True:
        palabra = next(iterador)
        if palabra.isnumeric():
            dias = int(palabra)
            break
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Fecha mal formada: {fecha}")

    #   Seguido de la palabra "días"
    palabra = next(iterador)
    if palabra not in lista_dias:
        raise ValueError(f"Se esperaba 'dias'")

    #   Seguido de la palabra "despues" o "antes"
    palabra = next(iterador)
    if palabra not in ["después", "despues", "antes"]:
        raise ValueError(f"Se esperaba 'antes/después'")
    else:
        antesdespues = palabra

    try:
        #   Puede que la frase termine en la palabra 'antes/después'
        palabra = next(iterador)
        #   Alternativa 1: "de/del [día] aaaa-mm-dd"
        if palabra in ["del", "de"]:
            #   Ignorarla
            palabra = next(iterador)

        if palabra in lista_dias:    # descartar palabra 'dia'
            palabra = next(iterador)
        #   Puede que venga la fecha, o si no cualquier otra expresión.
        try:
            año, mes, dia = palabra.split('-')
            if año.isnumeric() and mes.isnumeric() and dia.isnumeric():
                fecha = palabra
        except ValueError:
            pass # No era una fecha
    except StopIteration:
        pass

    return dias, antesdespues, fecha
```

Como funciona: tomamos la subfrase, eliminamos los signos molestos y la dividimos en palabras.

Luego hay que buscar el entero que comienza la expresión. Eso nos da la cantidad de días.

Seguimos leyendo, saltando lo que no interesa, en busca de "antes" o "después". Al encontrarlos, tenemos la relación.

Después de eso tiene que venir la fecha en formato "aaaa-mm-dd". Si no se encuentra, dejamos la fecha en `None`, y lo solucionamos en el llamante.

Si alguno de estos pasos no se encuentra lo que corresponde, se genera una excepción `ValueError`.

#### Armar la frase

La función `combinar()` recibe una frase completa, la divide en dos subfrases y las pasa a `analizar()` para que devuelva días, relación y fecha.

Si alguna de las fechas es `None` (la subfrase no la menciona explicitamente), se copia la otra fecha.

```
def combinar(frase):
    #   Recibe una frase "fecha 1 o fecha 2" y
    #   la retorna normalizada.

    fecha1, fecha2 = test.split(" o ")
    dias1, ad1, f1 = analizar(fecha1)
    dias2, ad2, f2 = analizar(fecha2)
    if f1 is None:
        f1 = f2
    if f2 is None:
        f2 = f1
    return f"{dias1} días {ad1} del {f1} o {dias2} días {ad2} del {f2}"
```

#### Demo

```
tests= ["8 dias despues del 2022-12-22 o 10 dias antes de este",  #example 1
        "8 dias despues del dia 2022-12-22 o 10 dias despues de ese dia en donde paso",  #example 2
        "8 dias antes o 9 dias antes del 2022-12-22",  #example 3
        "2 dias despues o 1 dia antes del 2022-12-22, dia en donde ocurrio",  #example 4
        "a tan solo 2 dias despues de 2022-12-22 o a caso eran 6 dias despues, mmm no recuerdo bien",  #example 5
        "a tan solo 2 dias despues de 2022-12-22 o a caso eran 6 dias despues de 2022-12-18, mmm no recuerdo bien"
        ]

for test in tests:
    print()
    print(test)
    print(combinar(test))
```

produce:

```
8 dias despues del 2022-12-22 o 10 dias antes de este
8 días despues del 2022-12-22 o 10 días antes del 2022-12-22

8 dias despues del dia 2022-12-22 o 10 dias despues de ese dia en donde paso
8 días despues del 2022-12-22 o 10 días despues del 2022-12-22

8 dias antes o 9 dias antes del 2022-12-22
8 días antes del 2022-12-22 o 9 días antes del 2022-12-22

2 dias despues o 1 dia antes del 2022-12-22, dia en donde ocurrio
2 días despues del 2022-12-22 o 1 días antes del 2022-12-22

a tan solo 2 dias despues de 2022-12-22 o a caso eran 6 dias despues, mmm no recuerdo bien
2 días despues del 2022-12-22 o 6 días despues del 2022-12-22

a tan solo 2 dias despues de 2022-12-22 o a caso eran 6 dias despues de 2022-12-18, mmm no recuerdo bien
2 días despues del 2022-12-22 o 6 días despues del 2022-12-18

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Realmente no se me habría ocurrido plantearle asi, muchísimas gracias por la ayuda y por el tiempo en la explicación y su detalle. Sos un crack encerio.